# Adaptive Trigger Not Working in Windows 10 UWP

Tags: xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I have created an adaptive trigger with three setters when the minWindowWidth>=0. But its not working. I looked into a similar question here but in that case the adaptive trigger was outside the grid. Even though the adaptive trigger is in the grid its not working. I have attached the implementation.The grid is initially set to collapsed but it is set visible once a custom condition is met.

```xaml
<Grid x:Name="loginGrid" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <!--Adaptive trigger for setting grid width and height-->
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="9"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="titl.Text" Value="Test"/>
                    <Setter Target="Login.Content" Value="Test"/>
                    <Setter Target="loginGrid.Margin" Value="12,500,12,500"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
         </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="7*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="titl" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="{StaticResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Register No" Padding="10,10,10,10" FontSize="{StaticResource SearchBoxContentThemeFontSize}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="regNo" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" FontSize="{StaticResource SearchBoxContentThemeFontSize}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" InputScope="Number"/>
    <Button x:Name="Login" Content="Login" Click="Login_Click" Background="{ThemeResource AppBarBackgroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="{StaticResource SearchBoxContentThemeFontSize}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing anything wrong with your code regarding the adapative trigger.

The error is more a margin error along with a row height error. You are using 500px top/bottom margins so sou will need to have a screen with more than 1000px height to see something.
You are also misusing the star notation for the rows height. A star means a fraction of the available space.

For example, the following :

```
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
<RowDefinition Height="*"/>
<RowDefinition Height="8*" />
```

means that the first row will take 10% of the available space for the grid, the second  10% too and the latest 80%. **BUT, if the available space is 0px, all rows will have a 0px height.**

If you set the top/bottom margin to smaller values and let the rows which have fixed height content (like text, buttons etc.) take the space they need (set height to *auto*), it will work.

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="7*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I've changed the first and 4th rows height to auto so the content will always be displayed no matter of what the display size is.

Regarding the AdaptiveTrigger, do not forget that the minimum window size for UWP application is 320 px so setting a minimum width to 9px will end in the trigger always been active.

Comment: I had set the minWindowWidth to 720 and the top and bottom margins to 50 and 200 respectively in the first place. But it didnt work. So thats why i changed the minWindowWidth to 9 so that it gets triggered everytime and also changed the margin to see a difference.

Comment: And I dont have a windows phone emulator. so i test the adapive trigger in   my desktop app. does resizing the app invoke the adaptive trigger?

Comment: Have you tried with the grid definition I've proposed with the first and 4th rows height set to auto ? You can also use the Live Tree Explorer from VS 2015 to control how/where your controls are drawn. You can use it to check which properties/styles are applied on a control.

Comment: I had a SplitView outside this grid... Thatswhy the trigger didnt work. Now after placing it outside the grid it works...